# Azure AKS static IP Address

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Currently per Microsoft documentation you can set a static IP address on the resource group of the kubernetes service. Problem with this is if you delete the resource group  / cluster then the static IP address is also gone.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip

Is there a way to connect Reserved IP address in Azure to link to AKS so that the IP address is guaranteed ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there are two types of the public IP in Azure, such as dynamic and static. But whether it is static or dynamic, we cannot set a specific IP ourselves. The IP is randomly assigned by Azure. The types just describe the lifetime of the Public IP.

Just the IP included in the Vnet which we designed can be assigned to a specified one with the static type as we want.

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/aks/static-ip

Comment: why do you copy existing answer without adding anything to it?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Could you tell me where is the existing answer? This is my personal opinion.

Comment: @charles Xu , What's the point of having Reserved IP's in Azure when you can't use them everywhere including aks (load balancer's).   sorry for my ignorance here,  is there an easy way todo this Vnet as suggested  (I assume the vnet sits on top of the load balancer). perhaps a link to document for configuration (this is becoming complicated)    ;))

Comment: @4c74356b41 Please pay attention to the time of the two answers.

Comment: @user3385105 I'm not sure what is the core you care about. You should pay attention to the document you posted. The public IP is created before the Kubernets cluster and it is certain after created. Come to Vnet, you set the scope for it and you can assign all of the IPs in the Vnet except the reserved four by Azure. By the way, the public in the side of the Internet, the Vnet in the side of Azure and the load balancer put them connected together so that we can access the Internet from private IP in Vnet.

Comment: @4c74356b41 It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

In the ARM deployment model, a Public IP Address (PIP) is an entity/resource all of its own. A PIP's are available as either dynamic or static. Dynamic is cheaper, static is more expensive as there is a finite amount of them in IPv4.

Yes, you can assign a PIP to AKS - see reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#use-a-static-ip-address-outside-of-the-node-resource-group

To ensure you don't lose your PIP, keep that in a seperate Resource Group from the Resource Group that contains resources that are volatile that may be deleted often.

Comment: looking at the docs you need a resource group and an AKS cluster name , therefor you can't create a separate resource group as you then need to create also an AKS cluster within the resource group. So I guess if u delete cluster then ip will also be gone.

Comment: You can deploy resources in more than one resource group. PIP can go in RG1 and your AKS can go into RG2. If you delete RG2, RG1 resources are untouched. That's all i was trying to say.